# %endwith% before %empty% (in Django template)

Tags: django, django-templates

Need to clarify a quick concept.

Experimenting within a Django template, I have found that this is legit:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
{% with forms|get_item:object.id as replyform %}

{% endwith %}
{% empty %}
Sorry, the object list is empty!
{% endfor %}
```

Whereas, the following gives me a `TemplateSyntaxError` error (`Invalid block tag: 'empty', expected 'endwith'`):

```
{% for object in object_list %}
{% with forms|get_item:object.id as replyform %}

{% empty %}
Sorry, the object list is empty!
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

What's the reasoning behind the former being legit, and not the latter? Don't exactly see anything regarding this in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to properly nest tags. If you used indentation, it becomes clearer:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {% with forms|get_item:object.id as replyform %}
    {% endwith %}
{% empty %}
    Sorry, the object list is empty!
{% endfor %}
```

Whereas this doesn't make sense:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {% with forms|get_item:object.id as replyform %}
{% empty %}
    Sorry, the object list is empty!
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

The entire `with/endwith` statement needs to live *inside* the block in which you start it. That block is the `for/empty/endfor` block, but specifically the block between `for` and `empty`.

If you think about it, the `with` is applied each time round the loop, for each item in the loop. Only the bit between `for` and `empty` is run each time round the loop - the bit between `empty` and `endfor` isn't. So how can you start a `with` block *every* time you loop, but only close it once (or never, as if the loop is empty, the `with` would never be called but the `endwith` would)? It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Nice way to explain it Ben. Thanks!

Comment: @HassanBaig no problem! Please accept the answer if it helped :)